# How do I call screenmanager in python file part to change screens only when all spinners are selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I've made a previous post here (Triggering screenmanager to change screen in Kivy from an if conditional) by attempting the same task in a different method. I didn't get any solutions there, so I'm trying a different method. However, I'm encountering different problems now.

I'm creating a day and time-selection option for the user. For that, I'm trying to create a button that only moves to the next screen (when clicked) when all the spinners have values selected.

For the program to identify when the spinners have been clicked (The day, hour and minute spinners), I have assigned a 'True' value for state (d_state, m_state, h_state and A_state for day, minute, hour, Am/Pm respectively) in the .py code for each of the spinners.

The screenmanager will shift from screen_two to screen_three only if all of the spinners have a state: True. I assign True when the spinner is clicked on (and an option is selected).

Most of the code works as expected, except for the self.screen_manager.current = 'screen_two' line in the switch_screen function in class ScreenTwo. I know this because I initially replaced the self.screen_manager.current = 'screen_two' line with a few print statements to debug, and they worked perfectly. This means only the screen_manager line is not working.

I have created a runnable version of my code (that displays my problem) with the bare minimum amount of code possible.

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenTwo>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            size: (400, 130)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            pos_hint: {'right': 0.6, 'center_y': 0.3}
            on_press:
                root.hours_checking()
                root.switch_screen()
        Spinner:
            id: day
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 44
            pos_hint: {'center': (.5, .5)}
            text: 'Day'
            values: 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'
            on_text:
                root.on_day_select(self.text)
                self.curr_selection: 'True'
        Spinner:
            id: hours
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 44
            pos_hint: {'center': (.1, .5)}
            text: 'Hour'
            values: '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'
            on_text:
                root.on_hours_select(self.text)
                self.curr_selection: 'True'
        Spinner:
            id: minutes
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 44
            pos_hint: {'center': (.3, .5)}
            text: 'Minutes'
            values: '00', '15', '30', '45'
            on_text:
                root.on_minutes_select(self.text)
                self.curr_selection: 'True'
        Spinner:
            id: AmPm
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 44
            pos_hint: {'center': (.4, .5)}
            text: 'AM/PM'
            values: 'a.m', 'p.m'
            on_text:
                root.on_AmPm_select(self.text)
                self.curr_selection: 'True'
""")

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def on_day_select(self, text): #Function assigns selected day from spinner to a variable
        global day, d_status
        day = str(text)
        d_status = 'True'

    def on_hours_select(self, text): #Function assigns selected 12-hour from spinner to a variable
        global hours, h_status
        hours = int(text)
        h_status = 'True'

    def on_minutes_select(self, text): #Function assigns selected minute from spinner to a variable
        global minutes, m_status
        minutes = int(text)
        m_status = 'True'

    def on_AmPm_select(self,text): #Function assigns selected a.m/p.m from spinner to a variable
        global AmPm, A_status
        AmPm = str(text)
        A_status = 'True'

    def hours_checking(self): #Function converts 12hr time to 24hr time
        global AmPm
        global hours
        global minutes
        global day
        try:
            if 1 <= hours <= 11 and AmPm == 'a.m':
                pass
            elif 1 <= hours <= 12 and AmPm == 'p.m':
                hours += 12
            elif hours == 12 and AmPm == 'a.m':
                hours = 0
        except:
            print('error1') #This line was used for my debugging output
        else:
            try: #This line is for the case when hours and AmPm are selected, but the other variables aren't
                print(day, hours, minutes)
            except:
                print('error2') #This line is used for my debugging output

    def switch_screen(self): #This function checks that all spinners have selected values
        global d_status, h_status, m_status, A_status
        try:
            if d_status == h_status == m_status == A_status == 'True': 
                self.screen_manager.current = 'screen_two' #This line does not execute for some reason, and the screen does not switch even if all the spinners have values selected
            else:
                pass
        except:
            print('error3') #This line was used for my debugging output
    pass


class ScreenThree(Screen):
    pass

# The ScreenManager controls moving between screens
screen_manager = ScreenManager()

# Add the screens to the manager and then supply a name
# that is used to switch screens
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name="screen_two"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenThree(name="screen_three"))


class KivyTut2App(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen_manager


sample_app = KivyTut2App()
sample_app.run()
```

Comment: You've now created three questions which are basically the same; if there was a problem with your question you should edit it, not post a new one.

Comment: @kaya3, my apologies. I have deleted the repetitive post. Will edit my posts in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for creating a single self-contained example, this is much better. You could still shorten it by removing some of the Spinners, since they're all identical in the important code, but it's okay for now.

The biggest problem with your code is your use of bare excepts, `except:`. These catch all exception types so you're left with no idea about why they're happening, and they only serve to hide real problems. Instead, it would be good practice to use `except SomeSpecificException:` to handle the specific problem you're expecting to encounter, that way if something else is wrong your program will still crash - which is what you want, because you haven't planned for that thing and there's no sensible way to continue.

If you remove the `error3` bare except then your problem is revealed:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "so06.py", line 123, in switch_screen
     self.screen_manager.current = 'screen_two'
 AttributeError: 'ScreenTwo' object has no attribute 'screen_manager'
```

Your problem is that you're trying to access the `screen_manager` attribute of the Screen, but no such attribute exists. If you read the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html), you'll find that what you actually want to access is `self.manager`.

Other issues:

- The screen still won't actually change, because you set `current` to `"screen_two"` which is the name of the currently-active screen.
- Don't use `'True'` to indicate that something has happened, use the actual boolean value `True`.
- Don't use global variables, for all the normal reasons that you can look up. Especially, don't use them without initialising them, that means your code raises a NameError if the button is clicked before these variables exist. Maybe that's why you added the bad `except:` lines, but that only makes things worse. The neater solution would be to use properties of the ScreenTwo object, which you can initialise to sensible values (i.e. `False`) then set to `True` later.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has helped me identify a lot of my crappy programming practices. I'll do my best to implement your suggestions in the future.